# Magento site is down again and again

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

My Magento site was down yesterday don't know the reason. But after searching i found manually clearing the files in cache **/var/cache/** and session **/var/session/** directories solve the problem.

My problem is, the site is down again today and again i cleared these directories solved the issue.

I need a permanent solution for this please help.

Comment: Does your site goes into maintenance mode when its down ?

Comment: May be you need more server space for your site to run

Comment: No, it shows a blank page and in firebug it shows 503 service not available.

Comment: Do you see ` maintenance.flag` in your Magento root directory ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Contact server provider and check if the server space is enough to run a Magento website (magento creates session, cache files inside the file system).
2. Check file/folder permissions are correct (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html).
3. If you need to clear cache directory automatically, ask the server provider to setup a cronjob to clear the cache directory in a specific time period (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84186/automatically-refresh-cache).

Note: this issue is not related to Magento installation, this is something related to the server. Also ask Magento related question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check this with the hosting team regarding the space issue.